# How to make elastic search more flexible?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am currently using this elasticsearch DSL query:

```
{
    "_source": [
        "title",
        "bench",
        "id_",
        "court",
        "date"
    ],
    "size": 15,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "i r coelho",
                    "fields": [
                        "title",
                        "content"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": [],
            "should": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "i r coelho",
                    "fields": [
                        "title.standard^16",
                        "content.standard"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "pre_tags": [
            "<tag1>"
        ],
        "post_tags": [
            "</tag1>"
        ],
        "fields": {
            "content": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what's happening. If I search for `I.r coelho`it returns the correct results. But, if I search for `I R coelho` (without the period) then it returns a different result. How do I prevent this from happening? I want the search to behave the same even if there are extra periods, spaces, commas etc.

Mapping

```
{
    "courts_2": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "author": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                },
                "bench": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                },
                "citation": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "content": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "standard": {
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                },
                "court": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "date": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "id_": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "standard": {
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                },
                "verdict": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Settings:

```
{
    "courts_2": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "highlight": {
                    "max_analyzed_offset": "19000000"
                },
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "provided_name": "courts_2",
                "creation_date": "1581094116992",
                "analysis": {
                    "filter": {
                        "my_metaphone": {
                            "replace": "true",
                            "type": "phonetic",
                            "encoder": "metaphone"
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": {
                        "my_analyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "my_metaphone"
                            ],
                            "tokenizer": "standard"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "MZSecLIVQy6jiI6YmqOGLg",
                "version": {
                    "created": "7010199"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT
Here are the results for `I.R coelho` from     `my analyzer` -  `{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "IR",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 3,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "KLH",
            "start_offset": 4,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}`

Standard analyzer:

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "i.r",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 3,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "coelho",
            "start_offset": 4,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: we would need to know the mapping of your index, could you please post it?

Comment: also, unrelated to your question, what's the point of having the `multi_match` queries both in a `must` and in a `should` boolean block?

Comment: Hi! I have edited in the mapping. As far as the logic is concerned, i dont really know. I inherited this code from someone else for a quick turnaround project. Please feel free to correct if it is wrong. @glenacota

Comment: you are using a custom analyzer called `my_analyzer`. Could you please post its definition? (`GET <your_index>/_settings`)

Comment: I apologize for not including that. I have edited it in. @glenacota

Comment: Hi, have you checked the updates on my answer? Do you consider your question answered? I don't have much to add, the only thing I could do more would be to sit with you reviewing your business requirements, queries and mappings, which I'd say it goes beyond just being a contribution on stack overflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason why you have a different behaviour when searching for `I.r coelho` and `I R coelho` is that you are using different analyzers on the same fields, i.e., `my_analyzer` for `title` and `content` (`must` block), and `standard` (the default) for `title.standard` and `content.standard` (`should` block).

The two analyzers generate different tokens, thus determining a different score when you're searching for `I.r coelho` (e.g., 2 tokens with the standard analyzer) or `I R coelho` (e.g., 3 tokens with the standard analyzer). You can test the behaviour of your analyzers by using the `analyze` API (see the [Elastic Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/test-analyzer.html)).

You have to decide whether this is your desired behaviour.

**Updates (after requested clarifications from OP)**

The results of the `_analyze` query confirmed the hypothesis: the two analyzers lead to a different score contribution, and, subsequently, to different results depending on whether your query includes symbol chars or not.

If you don't want the results of your query to be affected by symbols such as dots or upper/lower case, you will need to reconsider what analyzers you want to apply. The ones currently used will never satisfy your requirements. If I understood your requirements correctly, the [`simple` built-in analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html) should be the right one for your use case.

In a nutshell, (1) you should consider to replace the `standard` built-in analyzer with the `simple` one, (2) you should decide whether you want that your query applies different scores to the hits based on different analyzers (i.e., the phonetic custom one on the value of the `title` and `content` fields, and the `simple` one on their respective subfield).

Comment: Ahh makes sense. I tried using the ```_analyze``` API and using both the analyzers it returned ```I R coelho``` as three tokens. This is not the behaviour I want though. What I want is that, for both, ```I.R coelho``` and ```I R coelho``` the same results appear. What do I do?

Comment: What happens when you analyse the text "I.R coelho" with the `standard` and `my_analyzer` analyzers?

Comment: I apologise for replying late. I have edited in the details. Thank you!

Comment: Update my answer, but I just provided more elements for you to make **your** decisions, as there's no unique answer to your problem. I hope I helped you better understand the trade-offs